# Apply a function only to a specific type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, string, object

I want to sort an array of objects by either a string or a number.  If it is a string, I want to call `.toLowerCase()` on it first.  I'm making that distinction using `typeof` in the condition of a ternary statement.

```
interface ObjectProps {
    sortFoo: string,
    sortBar: number
}

const sortBy: "sortFoo" | "sortBar" = getSortKey();

const sortList = (...args: ObjectProps[]): number => {
    const compare: (string | number)[] = args.map(
        (arg: ObjectProps): string | number => typeof arg[sortBy] === 'string' ? arg[sortBy].toLowerCase() : arg[sortBy]
    );

    return compare[0] < compare[1] ? -1 : 1;
}

const objects: ObjectProps[] = getArrayOfObjects().sort(sortList);
```

This code will run just fine, but TS flags `.toLowerCase()` with this error:

```
TS2339: Property  toLowerCase  does not exist on type  string | number 
Property  toLowerCase  does not exist on type  number
```

How do I tell the TS engine that if `typeof myVar === 'string'` evaluates as false, then `myVar` is not a string?

I tried replacing the ternary with a full `if` clause, as in [this tutorial](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/baby-steps-typescript) (scroll down to the section titled "Unknown"), but TS still showed the same error.  Not sure what else to try.

Comment: ① What's `getSortKey()`, `getArrayOfObjects()`, etc? Could please you [edit] the code to be a [mre] that we can paste into our own IDEs and the only issue present is the one you have?  That is, could you clear up any problems [seen in this IDE](https://tsplay.dev/wEjO3N) except for the one you're asking about?  ② This is likely to be [ms/TS#56389](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56389) and the approach is probably to copy `arg[sortBy]` to a new variable before doing your tests, but without a [mre] I can't say for certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Typescript only performs that type narrowing on a variable, not necessarily a property that you're accessing. So you just need to store the property in a variable first, something like this:

```
const sortList = (...args: ObjectProps[]): number => {
    const compare: (string | number)[] = args.map(
        (arg: ObjectProps): string | number => {
          const sortVal = arg[sortBy];
          return typeof sortVal === 'string' ? sortVal.toLowerCase() : sortVal;
        }
    );

    return compare[0] < compare[1] ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: You bet! Happy typing! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this hopefully this will help you

```
const sortList = (...args: ObjectProps[]): number => {
const compare: (string | number)[] = args.map(
    (arg: ObjectProps): string | number => {
        if (typeof arg[sortBy] === 'string') {
            //--> arg[sortBy] is a string
            return (arg[sortBy] as string).toLowerCase();
        } else {
            //--> arg[sortBy] is not a string
            return arg[sortBy];
        }
    }
);

  return compare[0] < compare[1] ? -1 : 1;
}
```